# Add fields to email

Tags: email, drupal, workflow, drupal-rules

I am looking for the syntax to add node fields to the body of an email. Examples I looked at  the documentation, and the format is [content_type:content_type_title].

However, my email arrives with just the string [content_type:content_type_title].

Even better would be a PHP snippet that loads the node and dumps filed title and filed value into the body of the message.

Comment: syntax is actually [node:field] not [contente_type:field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules supports the Token module, which should allow you to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use node_load($nid) or db_query to get the node you want, use that in the email function you are creating.

Comment: I am using Rules module "wizard". I am not sure if I can add PHP directly to body of message without writing a hook-module.